# When do I have to use load() on collection

Tags: magento2, collection

I can meet many different approaches when using collections in Magento 2. Rarely, but sometimes I see that functions `load()` is used. Although without it there is no problem with accessing collection or its items. So what is the purpose of using it and do we really need `load()` collection in some situations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just need to iter a collection there is no reason to call `load`.

If you see the basic implementation in `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection`, method `load` is automatically called every time you try to access information.

Example:

```
public function getFirstItem()
{
    $this->load();

    if (count($this->_items)) {
        reset($this->_items);
        return current($this->_items);
    }

    return $this->_entityFactory->create($this->_itemObjectClass);
}
```

Or:

```
/**
 * Retrieve collection items
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject[]
 */
public function getItems()
{
    $this->load();
    return $this->_items;
}
```

For example, even method `walk` and `each` use a call to `getItems()`, so a call to `load` is **always done**.

I think you **only need to call `load`** when you need (for some reason) to load collection meta information before accessing items.

For example if you need to access filters or you need to  trigger `beforeLoad` events on your items (see implementation of `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection::load()` ).

This is only my opinion, I cannot see any reference in Magento 2 docs.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by `meta information` in context of collection?

Comment: Like collection filters.

Answer (score 0):

with collection->load() you will get full custom attributes
see \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Form\Attribute\Collection::_beforeLoad

```
protected function _beforeLoad()
{
    $select = $this->getSelect();
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $entityType = $this->getEntityType();
    $this->setItemObjectClass($entityType->getAttributeModel());

    $eaColumns = [];
    $caColumns = [];
    $saColumns = [];

    $eaDescribe = $connection->describeTable($this->getTable('eav_attribute'));
    unset($eaDescribe['attribute_id']);
    foreach (array_keys($eaDescribe) as $columnName) {
        $eaColumns[$columnName] = $columnName;
    }

    $select->join(
        ['ea' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute')],
        'main_table.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id',
        $eaColumns
    );
```